Enum reference variable to show as output in a table in java
I have a Enum class named Status. I have a table of "servers" that I would like to show the Status of them in the table output.
When I run a while loop, and perform a result set, it does not recognise the Enum reference variable when I try to retrive data from the row which has the Enum values.
This line is the issue im referring to -
Status status;
status = rs.getString("status");
I get error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Status". How do I get it work?
public void pingServer(String theServerId) throws Exception{
        Connection myCon = null;
        PreparedStatement myStmt = null;
        PreparedStatement myStmt2 = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        
        InetAddress inet = null;
        String ip;
        
        Status status = null;
//      String s = status.getStatus();
        Servers server = null;
        
        try {   
            int serverId = Integer.parseInt(theServerId);
            
            //get db connection
            myCon = dataSource.getConnection();
            
            //create sql to ping server
            String sql =  "select * from heartbeat.nodes";
            String sql2 = "UPDATE heartbeat.nodes SET status = ? WHERE (nodeId = ?)";

            
            //
            myStmt = myCon.prepareStatement(sql);
            myStmt2 = myCon.prepareStatement(sql2);
            
            myStmt.setObject(1, status.getStatus());
            myStmt.setInt(2, server.getNodeId());
            
            rs = myStmt.executeQuery(sql);
                
            while(rs.next()) {
                ip = rs.getString("ipAddress");
                inet = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
                serverId = rs.getInt("nodeId");
                status = rs.getString("status");
                
                if(inet.isReachable(100)) {
                    server.setStatus(Status.SERVER_UP);
                    myStmt2.executeUpdate();
                    
                } else {
                    server.setStatus(Status.SERVER_DOWN);
                    myStmt2.executeUpdate();

This line is the issue im referring to -
Status status;
status = rs.getString("status");
I get error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Status". Does it need converting ? if so how do you convert Enums.

What database are you using?

By the way, learn to use try-with-resources syntax to auto-close your connection, result set, etc.

Use:
status = Status.valueOf(rs.getString("status"));

Note the string must exactly match the values in your enum, including capitalization and should not include whitespace.
If it doesn't match it will throw an IllegalArgumentException
For example, if your Status enum is:
enum Status{
    ONLINE,
    OFFLINE
}

Then the string values "ONLINE" and "OFFLINE" will work, and the following will cause exceptions to be thrown: "Online", "OFFLINE ", etc...

Thanks for the reply.
I am still getting issues. I am trying to populate the mySql database "status" column with the enum refernces of either "server_up" or "server_down" I changed the config to:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Name is null
java.base/java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:291)
com.panoptech.monitoring.Status.valueOf(Status.java:1)
com.panoptech.monitoring.ServerData.getServers(ServerData.java:48)
com.panoptech.monitoring.ServersControllerServlet.listServers(ServersControllerServlet.java:172)

I changed to code to below:
while(rs.next()) {
ip = rs.getString("ipAddress");
inet = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
serverId = rs.getInt("nodeId");
status = Status.valueOf(rs.getString("status"));
if(inet.isReachable(100)) {
 server.setStatus(Status.SERVER_UP);
 myStmt2.executeUpdate();
 
} else {
 server.setStatus(Status.SERVER_DOWN);
 myStmt2.executeUpdate();
}


You passed in a null value, it throws an exception.  You need to handle null in your own code.  your call ends up here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-

If you want a generic solution, see Taylor's answer. The portable solution is indeed to store enums as strings in the database and convert to/from enums.
If you are using PostgreSQL, you can skip the conversion to/from string, and use enums directly. PostgreSQL supports enum types in tables. You can use a corresponding Java enum in your JDBC queries:
status = rs.getObject("status", Status.class);
...
myStmt.setObject(1, status, java.sql.Types.OTHER);

